# Guardar arreglos en base de datos

Tags: mariadb

Tengo arreglos que quiero guardar en la base de datos, los arreglos tienen alrededor de 1000 elementos, debo guardarlos en string o en que tipo?

```
    +--------------------+ 
    tabla caracteristicas 
    piel [datos] 
    ojos [datos] 
    expresiones  [datos]
   +--------------------+
```

debo guardar los arreglos completos y no asi elemento por elemento

en la bd puse

```
piel           varchar(1000) not null,
```

Pero si en caso de que mi arreglo piel tenga 2000 elementos? varchar(1000) ya no bastaria, necesito un tamaño ilimitado?

**Nota**: Ademas que si quiero guardar 1000 elementos con varchar(1000) tampoco abasteceria, por que ya que es string cuenta hasta los corchetes, comas...

cuando inserto con json (`VALUES (1,'{"data": {"language": "spanish", "age": 39}}',1,1);`) segun la respuesta de @Alfredo obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende, puedes valerte del formato de datos JSON, en los siguientes casos

1. MySQL 5.7
2. MySQL 8
3. MariaDB 10.2

**Importante**

> La sintáxis que te proporciono solo es enteramente para mariaDB, en
>   MySQL existen algunas variaciones al respecto de dichas funciones de
>   consulta de datos JSON

De este modo

```
MariaDB [blog]> CREATE TABLE persona(
    -> name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    -> attributes JSON NOT NULL);
```

> Aunque el formato es JSON internamente se trata como un LONG TEXT

**PARA INSERTAR**

```
MariaDB [blog]> INSERT INTO persona(name, attributes)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('alfredo', '{"data": {"language": "spanish", "age": 39}}');
```

**PARA CONSULTAR UN VALOR ESPECIFICO DEL JSON**

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT name, JSON_VALUE(attributes, '$.data.language') AS Data FROM persona;
+---------+---------+
| name    | Data    |
+---------+---------+
| alfredo | spanish |
+---------+---------+
```

**PARA CONSULTAR EL JSON COMPLETO**

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT name, JSON_QUERY(attributes, '$.data') AS Data FROM persona;
+---------+------------------------------------+
| name    | Data                               |
+---------+------------------------------------+
| alfredo | {"language": "spanish", "age": 39} |
+---------+------------------------------------+
```

**MAS SOBRE JSON**

Si haces el comando DESCRIBE persona; para checar mas acerca de la tabla te darás cuenta que de forma interna lo maneja como un LONG TEXT

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe persona;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name       | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| attributes | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```
Tu estructura pudiera quedar así

MariaDB [blog]> INSERT INTO persona(name, attributes)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('beto', '{"valor1": 1, "valor2": 2}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.098 sec)

MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM persona;
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| name    | attributes                                   |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| alfredo | {"data": {"language": "spanish", "age": 39}} |
| beto    | {"valor1": 1, "valor2": 2}                   |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Con fines tal vez solo estéticos**

Podemos usar la función JSON_DETAILED propia de mariaDB, (su equivalente en MySQL sería JSON_PRETTY) para obtener una mejor vista de la estructura

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT name, JSON_DETAILED(attributes) FROM persona;

+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name    | JSON_DETAILED(attributes)                                                     |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| alfredo | {                                                                             |
|         |     "data":                                                                   |
|         |     {                                                                         |
|         |         "language": "spanish",                                                |
|         |         "age": 39                                                             |
|         |     }                                                                         |
|         | }                                                                             |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: deberia guardar los datos en que tipo? string?

Comment: Añadí un ejemplo de cómo insertar @x-rw

Comment: disculpas pero no me di cuenta estoy usando mariadb

Comment: Es lo mismo @x-rw desde mariadb 10.2

Comment: estoy actualizando mariadb

Comment: @x-rw dame unas hrs y te mejoro la respuesta para darte un ejemplo completo de operaciones CRUD

Comment: deberia usar JSON_EXTRACT???

Comment: @x-rw revisa mi actualización

Comment: pero yo no tengo esta estructura '{"data": {"language": "spanish", "age": 39}}, la mia es un arreglo [1,2,2,3,4...]

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81857/discussion-between-alfredo-and-x-rw).

Comment: actualice mi pregunta, puse una imagen

Comment: creo que tu respuesta es acertada usando los tipos ,text, mediumtext, longtext...

Comment: se me agotan las ideas @x-rw serpa mejor esperemos otra respuesta de la comunidad que complemente o mejore lo ya expuesto saludos

Comment: no seria buena practica guardar el arreglo como string? mi arreglo no tiene clave para convertirlo en json